# Pulling a specific proxyaddress from AD using powershell

Tags: powershell, email, active-directory

I have a list of users in a csv file. This list contains users whose primary SMTP address is not internal to our organization. These are mail users who are having email forwarded elsewhere.

They have a proxyaddress listed in AD that is on their AD account that points to the organization and this is what I am trying to get to. The problem is that the proxyaddresses does not put the email in the same location so I need to somehow extrapolate the email(s). that match a certain criteria.

What I would really like to get at is the first.last@example.com or first_last.example.com without the {smtp: } formatting.

I have been able to produce a list of proxyaddresses but again it is just a list.

```
$users = import-csv $BadEmailList | % {Get-ADUser $_.LoginID -Properties proxyaddresses}

Foreach ($u in $users) {

    $proxyAddress = [ordered]@{}

    $proxyAddress.add(“User”,$u.name)

    For ($i = 0; $i -le $u.proxyaddresses.count; $i++)

   {

    $proxyAddress.add(“ProxyAddress_$i”,$u.proxyaddresses[$i])

    } #end for

[pscustomobject]$proxyAddress |

  Export-Csv -Path $ProxyAddressList -NoTypeInformation –Append -Force

  Remove-Variable -Name proxyAddress } #end foreach
```

What I am trying to get is the something similar to the following:

User            ProxyAddress_0
----            -----
User1           first.last@example.com

Comment: The proxyAddresses property is a list. So as you know there could be more than one address. Do you want all of those addresses to be exported or do you want a specific address for each user in the CSV? If you want a specific one, what is the criteria in order to find a match? What I'm looking for here is do you have a specific domain that you want to include or exclude or is there a particular alias format that you want to include or exclude? Is the intention that you have code that finds only first.last@example.com and you swap out the domain name to fit your environment?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in my description I have been trying to figure out how to get this working and it seems very clear in my head :-) Basically you are correct there are several domains in the proxy list. I want just one. So for example if you have the following:

user1@example1.com</br>
user2@example2.com</br>
user_1@example3.com</br>   

I want to get to only user2@example2.com and not the other 2.

Comment: Do you know what mailaddress you want based on a loginid or based on the emailaddress in the proxuaddress list?

Comment: I have the loginID. My issue is getting to the specific proxyAddress

Comment: How do you know which one of the proxyaddresses you want?

Comment: All the users have an address that is first.last@example.com in their proxy addresses but it is not their primary.  I need to extrapolate this address from the list for use.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the specific AD user with a given proxyaddress, as the header implies, you should be able to use a LDAP filter like this:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(proxyAddresses=*:first.last@example.com)))"
```

Comment: Will this work with my list of usernames? Every time I have tried to use the LDAPFilter with a list of login names it fails (most likely something I am doing wrong).

Comment: Well, I guess the question is still, how do you know, what proxyaddress you want? Is it any proxyaddress with a suffix not in your domain suffixes? What other info is in your $BadEmailList?

Comment: Isn't this pulling the user account from the proxy address? If so what I am trying to do is pull a specific proxy address from a list of known user accounts. So if a user has 5 proxy addresses in their proxyaddresses and I want the one that is first.last@example.com from all 100 users that is what I am trying to get to. The issue is that they are not all in the same location in the list of proxy addresses. The users Primary address is a different email than our domain so the domain account is one of the proxy addresses.

Comment: Yes, it is pulling a user baed on a specific proxyaddress. In your foreach loop you could do something like: ```$pa = $u.proxyaddresses |  where {$_ -match $('{0}.{1}' -f $u.givenName,$u.surname)``` but that requires, that the external email address is always formattet with first and last name as they appear in AD - that method would definitely be error prone unless the givnename and surname in AD is based on the external email address of the users.